# Display all remaining days in the current month in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

How can I display all the remaining days in the current month in react js / react-native ?
Its needs to look like this, I don't need CSS just javascript how to display it:

[image]

Comment: 1.Get number of days in current month.
2. Find current day
3. Subtract

Comment: Your question needs more polish. But here you can get what you want: https://www.code-sample.com/2015/07/remaining-days-in-current-month-in.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
now = new Date();

// Tota number of days in current month
const totalDays = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate();

// Today's day
const today = now.getDate();

// Remaining days of the month
const remainingDays = totalDays - today;
```

Comment: Thank you very much